# (Excel VBA) Variable doesn't work and brings up "Object Required error"

Tags: excel, vba

So I was testing a simple program to find the letter e and remove it from the cell. Except that Variable A doesn't work even though Cells(1,1) does.

```
Sub remove()
  A = Cells(1, 1)
  pos = InStr(A, "e")
       'A works for pos though I don't know why
  'A.characters(pos,1).delete'
       'The above doesn't work for some reason'   
  Cells(1, 1).Characters(pos, 1).delete    
End Sub
```

Things that I have tried

- Dim A as Range
- Using Range

Also Sorry for not being more specific about my problem. I'm not sure about the terminology behind VBA and coding in general though I'm working on it

Comment: I suggest you always use [Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement)

Answer (score 1):

Jeeped beat me to it. VBA is not strongly typed, so unless you explicitly tell it that the variable you are assigning is an object-type by using 'Set', the value that A takes is, in this case, the contents of the cell instead of the cell itself.

You don't even need to Dim it, although it is good practice.

```
Sub remove()
  Set A = Cells(1, 1) 'Need to use Set
  pos = InStr(A, "e")

  'This works just fine now
  A.characters(pos,1).delete'
End Sub
```

Comment: I get it I think.

So I'm making A=Cells(1,1).value by not typing set.

Thanks very  much :)

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning cells(1, 1).value to A. If you want the range object properties of cells(1, 1) (like 'characters') you need to Set a range-type var to cells(1,1).

```
Sub remove()
  dim A as range
  set A = Cells(1, 1)
  pos = InStr(A.value, "e")
  A.characters(pos,1).delete'   
End Sub
```